# Backbone route handlers not called on browser back button

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have Backbone routes like so:

route1 : http://localhost/#dash-campaigns/campaigns

route2 : http://localhost/#dash-campaigns/create

when i click on the browser back button when the user is in route2, the corresponsding routehandler functions are not called

My routes are defined as follows:

```
  routes: {
            "": "defaultRoute",
            "dash-campaigns/:query": "campView"
        }
```

This is basically happening becoz both of them have same hash, but note that the complete url is different. How do i solve this problem...?

Comment: Can you show the codes for `campView` function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable HTML5 `pushState`](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) to take advantage of hash events for route changes.